# Running 230VAC LED module at 400V

Tags: led, ac, voltage

I'm looking at a feedback LED from Eaton (their part # M22-LED230) which is rated to run at 85-264VAC. I'd like to use it to indicate if there is voltage present across 2 phases of a 400V 3 phase supply.

The datasheet shows it drawing 5-15mA within the rated voltage range. That would imply a nominal resistance of 17k.

What size resistor do I need to add in series? I'd be thinking enough to drop the additional ~136V, so at 15mA that would be minimum of 9k. Obviously the resistor will need to be able to with stand the voltage.

Is there anything else to consider?

Comment: If it represents a resistive load, and it can work at 85 Volts, you should operate it closer to 85 volts (maybe at 100 V). Your biggest pain point with all this will be dissipating the extra power. The larger resistor you use, the less extra power you will have to dissipate. If the LED does NOT present itself as a primarily resistive load, the series resistor scheme may not work like you want it to.

Comment: Yes, I'm concerned it will not act as a purely resistive load. Normally a LED has a voltage drop and then a resistor is used to limit current.
If I drop 315v and maintain 5mA that will require 63kOhm. The resistor will then dissipate ~1.6W. And it will need to be able to handle the voltage drop. There is another part in their catalog,   M22-XLED230-T, although it is confusing as to whether it is a resistor or a test switch. I'll order it and investigate

Comment: Yes 1.6 W is a lot. But if you use 9k, then I =~ 400 V /26 k = 15.3 mA. Then P = 0.0153 * 0.0153 * 9000 = 2.1 Watts. So the bigger the resistor, the less power you are wasting.

Comment: Voltage and power ratings for said resistor. Keep in mind that most 1/2 W resistors are specified at about 60 degree ambient and 175 degree resistor temperature, which may be fine for the resistor short term but turns anything adjacent to it to crisp. If it’s a one-off solution, go for 5 times the power rating needed or more. Please verify the voltage rating of the resistor too. Shouldn’t be an issue but please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer on the manufacturer's website.  They make an additional part ([M22-XLED230-T](https://datasheet.eaton.com/datasheet.php?locale=en_GB&model=231080)) which shows a use case driving the LED from a 400VAC supply. Confusingly it is labelled as an element to test the functioning of the LED (without activating the normal switch element).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it can work, the module is not that complicated.
If you can find a safe and cost effective way of mounting that resistor.

A relay with 400V coil or voltage monitor may be a better choice.

[image]
(white version)

*The cap is 120nF (in series), the resistor is 2k.
The small resistor is 1k.*

Comment: Replacing the capacitor with a higher voltage lower value one would be simpler...

Comment: @bobflux The capacitor is in series. Perhaps you can you can just add a capacitor in series instead of a resistor?

Comment: Yes you could definitely do that.

Comment: An additional series cap would be OK. Changing values in the module assumes its PCB is laid out with the correct clearance for 400V.

Comment: Thanks for the inside view. The datasheet shows a rated insulation voltage of 500V, and rated impulse withstand voltage of 6kV.

Comment: @DavidMoorhouse Yeah no problem, looks like the 24V is made by populating the other side of the board. Smart design.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to drive a 24VDC LED module from the control voltage of the controller.  This 24V is supplied by a SMPS that will have no output if the 400VAC input in the original question is not present.

The hesitation I have is that the switch for the 400VAC would be adjacent to the 24V LED module.  I can't find any guidance from the manufacturer (Eaton) about mixing modules of different voltages on their modular switches, but common sense tells me there would need to be some type of physical barrier rather than just relying on the voltage rating of the individual components.